# Is there a way to use types from a sequelize model in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

Is there a way to pass my types from the sequelize model to the typescript?

My model code:

```
import { Table, Column, Model, DataType } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
export class User extends Model {
    @Column({ type: DataType.UUID, defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4 })
    userId!: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    username!: string;

    @Column({ allowNull: false, unique: true })
    email!: string;

    @Column({ defaultValue: false })
    confirmed!: boolean;

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    password!: string;

    @Column({ defaultValue: false })
    isAdmin!: boolean;
}
```

Code in my route with instance fields of model, they all have type any:

```
const { userId, username, email, confirmed, password, isAdmin } = req.body;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `User` class as a type for `req.body`.

```
const { 
  userId, 
  username, 
  email, 
  confirmed, 
  password, 
  isAdmin
} = req.body as User
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQIYCMA2BTANHAYQkwFcQA7fAWQgBNtN8ARVGVZATzGzgF84AZlAgg4AcgDO2AI4kGwAF7YAtDC7YJAYyjAwMMQG4AUEYACaLNiPYAHpFhxNmVBIlwAqlKhxbMbOVo3GnpMRCM4CLhTIlIKAAokNW4ALjgWNk5uADp3dwBJJnx6AVQSTBgANVRSbFT09nUc-KYKgBY%20AEpwyJIvPNoAQlSJGB1yAHNjbojo4jJyBLhqzAgAdwA5MsxUkswpTum4XuwoclQQbCG4EbHJk0iomPnF5bXNzG3Baql8EnJgWS1OCjOQHB7YECoYCYK43YATKYPWaxBZIYqlcpVGo7b48XhdB6aCDkATAKAXQapdAQYjYVDkRGRZHPJCvDZbHF7PEEyJgFwSVbQSnXUbwu6HZnxNHYEplSrVOSc-b4w7ACQAQVoIHhV2ptPpxl4JiMRPIIzgUBkqSQ1NoHFS9I4fDgAF5EHBbfbEPwjSbieakN1jlB%20vgg14zhcwxEIVDGHBuqbSeTsLRo3A%20a5BVA0wmImrNdryEZ%20G7LdIsp6lm5PCcgA)

---

You should be a bit careful with the `User` type, as it includes a lot of extra functions like `$count()` or `$create()`. You should exclude them from the type when using it to type user input.

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>

const { 
  userId, 
  username, 
  email, 
  confirmed, 
  password, 
  isAdmin
} = req.body as NonFunctionProperties<User>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=44&pln=28&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQIYCMA2BTANHAYQkwFcQA7fAWQgBNtN8ARVGVZATzGzgF84AZlAgg4AcgDO2AI4kGwAF7YAtDC7YJAYyjAwMMQG4AUEYACaLNiPYAHpFhxNmVBIlwAqlKhxbMbOVo3GnpMRCM4CLhTIlIKAAokNW4ALjgWNk5uADp3dwBJJnx6AVQSTBgANVRSbFT09nUc-KYKgBY%20AEpwyJIvPNoAQlSJGB1yAHNjbojo4jJyBLhqzAgAdwA5MsxUkswpTum4XuwoclQQbCG4EbHJk0iomPnF5bXNzG3Baql8EnJgWS1OCjOQHB7YECoYCYK43YATKYPWaxBZIYqlcpVGo7b48XhdB6aCDkATAKAXQapdAQYjYVDkRGRZHPJCvDZbHF7PEEyJgFwSVbQSnXUbwu6HZnxNHYEplSrVOSc-b4w7ACQAQVoIHhV2ptPpxl4JiMRPIIzgUBkqSQ1NoHFS9I4fDgAF5EHBbfbEPwjSYkjx1sSAGJ-TQwYDEgAKwm4sA463OGgAPMgAHyu90AbQA0nB4XAANbYDgQAQoAC6qWQOfLPhsfgCbhD5DDEfIcAA-HByNgAG4nOCpXO8TNFktl5Dl4z%20uCB8jN1tRmMncPJtMZyPATQFlP4OcL8NLiCxtQJi4SFOp1MmU3mpDdY5Qfr4B9eM4XF8RCFQxhwbqm0lyWwWhPzgPlXEFKAQL-CI1U1bVyCMfg3UtaQsk9JY3H3UND3IaNjxXYBk08E5UyAA)

---

If you *only* want the properties you defined inside the `User` class without any inherited properties from `Model`, use this:

```
type WithoutModel<T> = Omit<T, keyof Model>

const { 
  userId, 
  username, 
  email, 
  confirmed, 
  password, 
  isAdmin
} = req.body as WithoutModel<User>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=35&pln=28&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQIYCMA2BTANHAYQkwFcQA7fAWQgBNtN8ARVGVZATzGzgF84AZlAgg4AcgDO2AI4kGwAF7YAtDC7YJAYyjAwMMQG4AUEYACaLNiPYAHpFhxNmVBIlwAqlKhxbMbOVo3GnpMRCM4CLhTIlIKAAokNW4ALjgWNk5uADp3dwBJJnx6AVQSTBgANVRSbFT09nUc-KYKgBY%20AEpwyJIvPNoAQlSJGB1yAHNjbojo4jJyBLhqzAgAdwA5MsxUkswpTum4XuwoclQQbCG4EbHJk0iomPnF5bXNzG3Baql8EnJgWS1OCjOQHB7YECoYCYK43YATKYPWaxBZIYqlcpVGo7b48XhdB6aCDkATAKAXQapdAQYjYVDkRGRZHPJCvDZbHF7PEEyJgFwSVbQSnXUbwu6HZnxNHYEplSrVOSc-b4w7ACQAQVoIHhV2ptPpxl4JiMRPIIzgUBkqSQ1NoHFS9I4fDgAF5EHBbfbEPwjSYkjwAOrAGAACwgJBgwQYAB5kAA%20V1wADy2pgsfwAGtsBwIAI4FHMHGTKbzUhuscoP18OWvGcLtWIhCoYw4N1TaTydhaA24HzXIKoN3WxE1ZrteQjPw3ZbpFlPUs3EHQ%20HI3QY54TnGgA)

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize provides a Utility Type `Attributes<M extends Model>` for this, if I am reading your question correctly. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/